# which deb package contains ros package X?

Tags: ubuntu, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm installing electric turtle from deb packages but could not find motion_planning_msgs.
Is there a way to know which deb package contains ros package X?
I tried to use `apt-file` but it didn't work for packages.ros.org

```
$ apt-file update
Ignoring source without Contents File:
  http://www.openrtm.org/pub/Linux/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Contents-amd64.gz
Ignoring source without Contents File:
  http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Contents-amd64.gz
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10830/which-deb-package-contains-ros-package-x?/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2011-08-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to find the ROS stack that the package is contained in.  The easiest way to do this is to go to the wiki page, e.g. http://www.ros.org/wiki/motion_planning_msgs .  You'll see in the navigation bar that it's part of 'arm_navigation', so the debian package is ros-electric-arm-navigation.

The next version of roslocate will also let you do this as well.  If you need it now you can fetch it from:

https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_release/trunk/rosinstall/scripts/roslocate

```
./roslocate describe motion_planning_msgs

Type: package
Stack: arm_navigation
Description: This package defines a set of general-purpose messages and services for motion planning and control. It includes messages that can be used to specify joint and cartesian trajectories, represent robot state and services to compute motion plans. It also includes a set of conversion methods that can be used to convert messages from one form to another.
URL: http://ros.org/wiki/motion_planning_msgs
```

Update:

Need to use --distro=electric to catch the issue that Kei notes in the comment:

```
./roslocate describe motion_planning_msgs --distro=electric
cannot locate information about motion_planning_msgs
```

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-08-05**:
Also relevant is this FAQ entry: http://www.ros.org/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_install_ROS_packages_from_.deb_files.3F. Perhaps it should be updated to mention roslocate.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-08-04**:
@kwc: done: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3623 Didn't exactly know which component to file it against (debian? rosbuild?), feel free to move / reassign

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-08-04**:
@AHornung: probably.  can you file a ticket?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-08-04**:
@Kei Okada: http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/ChangeList : 1.0.0 Collapsed motion_planning_msgs, collision_environment_msgs, geometric_shapes_msgs, planning_environment_msgs, and move_arm_msgs into arm_navigation_msgs.   Looks like the wiki is running against a different branch.

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2011-08-04**:
Thanks, now `dpkg -L  ros-electric-arm-navigation | grep motion_planning_msgs` returns null. Is motion_planning_msgs deprecated?

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-08-04**:
Ken, would it be possible to put the ROS package names into the .deb stack package description? That way the stack should also show up when using "apt-cache search ".